# CSS style for NOT nested item

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS/SASS to style a validity message.  The message is not nested within what I'm accessing.

For example my JavaScript adds an error class to the input box if it's not valid.  I want block visible attributes to change further down the page.

```
// when no error
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname
// then
div.tagname-available { display: block; } // NOT NESTED
// and
div.tagname-unavailable { display: none; } // NOT NESTED

// when error
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname.error
// then
div.tagname-available { display: none; } // NOT NESTED
// and
div.tagname-unavailable { display: block; } // NOT NESTED
```

In theory I should be able to access the elements without having to write JavaScript to perform this.  Possibly if CSS has a ROOT document variable like JavaScript's `$(document)` then I could do.

```
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname {
  $(document) > div.tagname-available { display: block; } // NOT NESTED
  $(document) > div.tagname-unavailable { display: none; } // NOT NESTED
}
```

And for the HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="200px">
      <span class="pull-right vf-labels">Choose your Tag ID</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="error" data-validate="/users/checktagname" id="user_tags_attributes_0_tagname" name="user[tags_attributes][0][tagname]" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="text-primary" style="font-size: small;">Check Availability</span><br />
      <div class="tagname-available">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-right:4px;"></span>
        <span class="text-success" style="font-size: small;">Available</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tagname-unavailable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-right:4px;"></span>
        <span class="text-danger" style="font-size: small;">Not Available</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Possibly I could use the [`:root`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/root/) selector for CSS?

Comment: `input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname.error +. Tagname-available{ css here} ` if I understand you correctly. Otherwise please add relevant html and javascript to your post.

Comment: Basically you can't do that. Please a class on an element in the hierarchy **above** the element which you want to control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3 Standard doesn't include reverse reference in CSS.  Nor is there a way to access another CSS attribute that is not either a sibling or child.  The only way to access CSS attributes in this way is the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the sibling selector.

```
// when no error  
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname +
.tagname-available { display: block; }
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname +
.tagname-unavailable { display: none; }

// when error  
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname.error +
.tagname-available { display: none; }
input#user_tags_attributes_0_tagname.error +
.tagname-unavailable { display: block; }
```

Comment: I tried this with jsfiddle.net and the display:block; stuff didn't perform.  I've gone ahead and written it in JavaScript for my project.